# Noun for a person who believes in ordinances?

Tags: terminology

A person who believes in sacraments is a "sacramentalist".  Is there a noun for a person who believes in church ordinances instead of sacraments?  "Non-sacramentalist" seems odd, as well as too broad in scope.  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the term ["Rigorist"](https://www.wordnik.com/words/rigorist) could be what you are looking for.

Comment: This looks more like a question about [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) than about Christianity.

Comment: Lee -- good suggestion!  I asked it here only because there's a good amount of theological understanding baked into the question, that might be lost on a language-only site.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be such a word. If an ordinant is someone who performs ordinances, i.e., one who ordains, then ordinantalist would be likely the word for one who believes in ordinances.